# connect YOLO with vgg classifier

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, yolo

I have a YOLO model to detect the location of traffic signs and I have another model that determine
what is the sign
my question is how can I send the detected signs from YOLO to the classifier then write the correct
label above the bounding box like the image below [image: this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use OpenCV for this. Load the pretrained models(`weights`, `cfg`, `caffemodel`, `prototxt`, `onnx`) using `readNet` or `readNetFrom...`.

For video use `OpenCV dnn blobFromImage` to pass each frame to yolo net which detects bounding boxes. You may need to do Non-maximum Suppression. Crop the bounding boxes based on confidence and again pass the cropped image to `dnn` vgg net which should give classification results.

To write labels get the `(x,y)` position of each bounding box and use `putText` with font size as offset on the original input image frame.

Comment: it worked, but it takes a very long time in testing  if I have a 1 min video it will run for 10+ min
to get the results is there something can I do to make testing faster than that

Comment: You can look into using Lower Resolution Video, `Frame Skipping`, `Tracking`, GPU, `Yolo Tiny`. Using `smaller input` size such as 256x256 instead of 416x416 can further provide speed up. Using `1 color channel` images instead of 3 if not specifically required. Using a `CNN architecture` with less parameters than VGG will improve performance. New `Yolo V4` and `V5` is available with training code. There is also Binary CNN. Some of the above will improve performance but at the cost of some accuracy.

Comment: I also found that OpenCV is not working with GPU now it's compatible with GPU on collab and they said that the testing speed will improve by 1500%
if you know anything about how to configure OpenCV with GPU I hope you provide my a link or something cuz it's new and almost there is no tutorial about how it works on collab